# Applicability of plant images from different continents

Tags: agriculture, deep-learning

There are several plant/weed image datasets from various places, like [Australia](https://github.com/AlexOlsen/DeepWeeds), [Germany](https://github.com/cwfid/dataset), [Latvia](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352340920307277)

Please forgive my ignorance on this question, but what is the applicability of this data when implemented on a production system on a different continent, say North America for example.

My background is in computer vision and computer science and less in agriculture.  To me, weeds that grow in Europe/Australia will look different to weeds growing on the common lawns of a United States home.

Some plants have species that have the name of the continent in them!  So is the different in shape/color etc liable to make this data unusable in another environment?